# $b=a^p+1$ is a perfect square. Show that $p|(b-9)$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

$p$ is  a prime, and $a$ is a positive integer, $b=a^p+1$ is a perfect square. Show  that $p|(b-9)$

It seem very interesting problem.if let $a^p+1=x^2$,it is clear $p\neq 2$

I have prove : $x$ is odd

proof:if $x$ is even number,then $(x+1,x-1)=1$,and note $a^p=(x+1)(x-1)$,then exist $r>s\ge 1\in N^{+}$ such  $x+1=r^p,x-1=s^p$
so
$$2=(x+1)-(x-1)=r^p-s^p=(r-s)(r^{p-1}+r^{p-2}s+\cdots+s^{p-1})
\ge p\ge 3$$which is contradiction

which is a pretty interesting and nice result. I wonder in which ways we may approach it.

Comment: no,this $(x+1,x-1)=1$,so $x+1,x-1$ both $p$th power

Comment: So $m^2=a^p+1$. By [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (nowadays Mihailescu's theorem) this implies that $p=3$, $a=2$, $m=3$. Undoubtedly a lower technology solution exists for this special case. Bringing this up just to stop friends from wasting time looking for more examples (with a view of trying to find a general pattern).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen See my answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,my problem is from middle school exam.

Comment: It seems like Fermat's little theorem could be used here, but really? from a middle school exam?

Comment: Chein’s ingenious solution of this special case of Catalan’s conjecture is here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041579

Comment: @KierenMacMillan That shows there is no solution for p>3. The case p=3 is still left. I have a feeling it is not trivial because if it was easy, why wasn't it included in the paper? Furthermore, I have not given up on the possibility that there is an elementary proof of the orginal question  since it does not necessarily require showing that there are no solutions for p>3, just that if there are any then p divides b-9. I do seriously doubt that the problem was asked on a middle school exam.

Comment: @JohnL: Maybe “middle of a graduate degree”? ;)

Comment: The problem can be formulated as $(2x)^p=4(y^p\pm1)\implies p\mid y\mp1$ where $x,y\ge1$.

Comment: @JohnL For $p = 3$ we are looking at integral points on an elliptic curve, and there are algorithms to find them all. But of course that's not elementary anymore.

Answer (score 5):

From the comments we have the elementary proofs that $x^2 = a^p + 1$ has no solutions for prime $p > 3$, so it suffices to prove that when $p = 3$, $x$ is divisible by $3$.

We have $\gcd(a+1, a^2-a+1) \mid 3$, so we can assume that they are coprime and hope for a contradiction. If they are coprime, then both are squares, say
$$\begin{align*}a+1 &= n^2 \\a^2-a+1 &= m^2 \,. \end{align*}$$
But $a^2 - a + 1 = m^2$ is impossible when $a > 1$, because
$$(a-1)^2 = a^2 - 2a + 1 < a^2 - a - 1 < a^2 \,.$$
This is our contradiction.

Comment: "If they are coprime, then both are squares" why ?

Comment: @AnasKhaled Because the product is $a^3+1 = x^2$. If the product of coprime numbers is a square, then both are squares.

Comment: @BartMichels I would like to add that the two coprime integers have to be positive.

Comment: Damn, that is a very beautifull proof. And people were saying in the comments that this cannot be a middle school exam problem.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Well, this is only the $p=3$ case. The other cases are much harder.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar: To get it down to the point where this (lovely!) proof is the final step requires three preliminary lemmas [cf. Nagell] and an incredibly clever and non-obvious descent proof [cf. Chein]. Since that took almost a hundred years to obtain, it is perhaps a little optimistic to think that a middle school student could solve it on an exam.

Answer (score 0):

I am in 8th grade, so please if I make mistakes in the calculation then please tell me, I would delete the answer.

You proved that $x$ is odd. That would mean that $x^2$ is odd too.

So the equation $x^2=a^p+1$

If we subtract $1$ from both sides then $a^p$ would be even. Which implies that $a$ is even.

Since $x$ is odd, $x=2k+1$ and since $a$ is even, $a=2n$

Putting these in the equation, we get:

$(2k+1)^2=(2n)^p+1$

$\implies 4k^2+4k+1=2^p n^p+1$

$\implies k(k+1)=2^{p-2}n^p$

Since one of $k$ and $k+1$ has to be even

So assume $k$ is even, then $k+1$ is odd.

Now consider the following:

If $n^p$ is even

Then $n$ is even

$2l(2l+1)=2^{p-2}n^p$

$\implies l=2m$

$\implies k=4m$

$\implies k\geq 4$

$\implies x\geq 9$

$\implies b-9 \geq 72$-----------$(1)$

AND, If $n^p$ is odd

Then $n$ is odd, so let $n=2\alpha+1$

By the comment of John L and Kieren MacNillan, it seems that $p$ cannot be greater than $3$ so consider the case $p=3$:

$2l(2l+1)=2(2\alpha+1)^3$

$\implies 2l^2+l=8\alpha^3+6\alpha^2+6\alpha+1$

$\implies l-1=2\beta$

$\implies l\geq 3$

$\implies k\geq 6$

$\implies x\geq 13$

$\implies b-9\geq 160$---------$(2)$

Assuming that the statement in the question is true, 3 cannot divide 160. Which means that $n$ can't be even.
So $n$ is odd.

So from $(1)$, we get $b\geq 81$

$\implies (2n)^3+1\geq 81$

$\implies n\geq\sqrt[3]{10}$

Since $n$ is a positive integer,

$n\geq\lceil \sqrt[3]{10} \rceil=3$

$\implies a\geq 6$

If the statement is not correct then $(2)$ can also be the case, then from $(2)$ we get $b\geq 169$

$\implies (2n)^3+1\geq 169$

$\implies n\geq\sqrt[3]{21}$

Since $n$ is a positive integer,

$n\geq\lceil\sqrt[3]{21}\rceil=3$

$\implies a\geq 6$

So in both cases $a\geq 6$

**These followings I derived in this answer might help you prove the statement:**

$●b-9\geq 72$ if the statement is correct. Otherwise $b-9\geq 72$ and $b-9\geq 160$ both could be the case.

$●a=2n\geq 6$ where $n$ is an odd number.

$●$The only $p$ to consider is $p=3$ by the comment of John L and Kieren MacMillan.